# why unable to compress scanned PDF in ghostscript?

Tags: pdf, compression, ghostscript

In older version 8.70 it was working but I had updated the ghostscript version 9.27 and now it's not compression the scanned pdf files. Can we have any other solution to compress pdf on linux server?

Below command I am using for the pdf compression

gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dDownsampleColorImages=true -dPrinted=true -dColorImageResolution=100 -dNOPAUSE  -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf

Sample file
https://easyupload.io/fe64dt

Comment: Ghostscript (more specifically the pdfwrite device) does not compress PDF files. What it does do is consume PDF files, process the marking content, and produce new PDF files. If the processing involves reducing the data then the new file will be smaller. It is impossible to guess from your description what may be going on with a 12 year old version of the software, you would have to post the original PDF file so it could be investigated. Quite possibly the old behaviour was a bug.

Comment: OK well the problem with that file is that it is not the original file. You have edited it, adding annotations, which markedly changes the content. Also, it is **trivial** to remove the annotations, revealing the data you wanted obscured. I strongly suggest you remove this file from the download site urgently!! Then find (or create) a file which doesn't have sensitive data and upload that. If this really is the file you are trying to 'compress' then my guess is that the 12 year old software didn't honmour the annotations and the current software does.

Comment: Oh, the other likely explanation is that in version 8.70 the JPEG compressed image would be decompressed, then recompressed again with the DCT (JPEG) filter. Because JPEG is a lossy compression filter, that would make the output image smaller, at the cost of quality. Current versions of the pdfwrite device don't touch the JPEG data unless they need to. Your image is 1372x1983 samples, and is drawn to fill a page 1372x1983 points in size. So the resolution is 1 pixel per point, which is 72 dpi. Since you have set the ColorImageResolution to 100, no downsampling occurs.

Comment: Hi Ken, Here I am sharing sample file link . Please check https://easyupload.io/fe64dt

Comment: Is there any alternate solution to compress this file?

Comment: The file is already compressed, the only way to make it smaller is to lose quality. You can change the ColorImageResolution and ColorImageDownsampleThreshold parameters to reduce the resolution of the image still further but that's as far as it goes. If you do that you probably want to change the ColorImageFilter to FlateEncode, to avoid applying JPEG lossy compression again. Fundamentally; it's a big image, what were you expecting ? The only way to reduce it's size is clever compression technology or reduced quality. You could try making a JPEG2000 image instead (not with GS though)

Comment: Hi KenS , After degrading the resolution I am able to compress. Thank you.